# What are meanings of 3 dimensions of smart phone?

Tags: screen, hardware

What are the three dimensions of a smartphone referring to?

Forexample As shown highlighted in attached snapshot , size is also highlighted and dimensions are also highlighted[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three dimensions are height, width, and thickness (depth) respectively. Size is the size of the display (screen) measured diagonally.